MYSQL query to pull data by groups
I have following data in tourament MySQL table.



id
name
team




1
Warren
A


2
Carol
B


3
Donna



4
William
A


5
Andrew
C


6
Neil
A


7
Max
A


8
Phil



9
William



10
Keith



11
Phil




I am trying to create a query to output the data in the following form to process it further.



name
team




A
1


B
1


C
1


Donna
0


Keith
0


Phil
0


Phil
0


William
0



Please have a look here for data.
Current attempt:
select COALESCE(NULLIF(`team`,''), `name`) as name, 
case
    when `team` = '' THEN false
    when `team` != '' THEN true
end as `group`
from `tournament` order by COALESCE(NULLIF(`team`, ''), `name`) ASC;


I don't understand how you get from your tournament table to that desired output. Can you explain?

@JNevill Please have a look at the sqlfiddle for data

I've added your current attempt to the question to help provide context. An explanation would still be helpful.

Your approach is good!
Try the below code to achieve the expected output:
SELECT 
    team AS name, 
    case
        when `team` = '' THEN false
        when `team` != '' THEN true
    end as `group` 
FROM tournament 
WHERE team IS NOT NULL AND team != '' 
GROUP BY team 
UNION ALL 
SELECT name, 0 AS team 
FROM tournament 
WHERE team IS NULL OR team = ''
ORDER BY name;


Thank you @Kousalya N for the answer! The solution indeed gives the desired output.

Your attempt is good, you just need to rewrite COALESCE(NULLIF(team,''), name) to COALESCE(team, name) because COALESCE will only move on to the next parameter if the current parameter is NULL. Since'' != NULL the name column will never be selected.
Something like:
SELECT COALESCE(team, name) as name, 
   CASE when team IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as group 
FROM tournament 
ORDER BY COALESCE(team, name);


Thanks @JNevill for clearing that out, however it doesn't offer the desired output.

Probably just need a DISTINCT or a GROUP BY to aggregate the records and you should be in the ballpark

Can you give an example?

Just drop the word DISTINCT in after the word SELECT and let 'er rip

It works also without union like this
SELECT 
    MAX(name) AS name,
    IF(team = '',0,1) as team
FROM tournament 
GROUP BY team,name
ORDER BY IF(team = '',1,0),name ASC;

result:
name    team
Andrew  1
Carol   1
Max     1
Neil    1
Warren  1
William 1
Donna   0
Keith   0
Phil    0
William 0

click here for a sample
